# CSS Image and text background color

Tags: html, css

I am looking to have background color exactly like

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div>
        <?php if (!empty($lot_image)): ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $lot_image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $lot_image['alt']; ?>">
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="caption checkout-caption">
            <h3 id="newpro"><?php echo "$monte_text"; ?></h3>
            <p class="details"><?php echo "$displaycenter6";?></p>
        </div>
```

How can I cover complete image and the text so they both will have same color without white space between them?

Comment: Please post your CSS code as well . thanks

Comment: Even if this is quite general, I think I know where is the problem, if you say you try to get rid of some white space... DON'T use H3. Format your own class with font size and so on. all headers have some default not null margins.